# PresentViewController crash on iOS 4.3 but not on iOS 5

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, sigabrt

Can anyone tell me why this code crashes with SIGABRT unrecognised selector sent to instance, on 4.3 simulator, but works just fine on iOS 5 simulator?

```
matchSetup = [[viewMatchSetup alloc]initWithNibName:@"viewMatchSetup" bundle:nil];
[matchSetup setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
[self presentViewController:matchSetup animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Thanks in advance

FIX: [self presentModalViewController:matchSetup animated:YES]; //Modal being the required change

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It crashes because the `presentViewController:animated:completion:` method of `UIViewController` is not available on iOS 4.3. It was introduced in iOS 5. Since you don't use the completion block, simply use the "old" method `presentModalViewController:animated:`:

```
[self presentModalViewController:matchSetup animated:YES];
```

Comment: You can perform the check with `respondsToSelector:` function

Comment: [self presentViewController:matchSetup animated:YES];

Oh hang, that doesn't work either. Same error.

Comment: [self presentModalViewController:matchSetup animated:YES] works

Comment: Ouch, even though I cited the method with the correct name, my example was wrong. Have fixed it.